# MLPclassifier from sklearn shows different accuracies when executed on other machine?

Tags: python, numpy, random, scikit-learn

It looks like running the sklearn MLPclassifier with the same input on different devices will give different accuracy results, even if a global seed is set.

MWE:

```py
import numpy as np
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

np.random.seed(1)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.1, stratify=y, random_state=np.random.RandomState(0))

nn = MLPClassifier(hidden_layer_sizes=(100,100),
                   activation='relu',
                   solver='adam',
                   alpha=0.001,
                   batch_size=50,
                   learning_rate_init=0.01,
                   max_iter=1000,
                   random_state=np.random.RandomState(0))

nn.fit(X_train, y_train)


y_train_pred = nn.predict(X_train)
acc_train = np.sum(y_train == y_train_pred, axis=0) / X_train.shape[0]
y_test_pred = nn.predict(X_test)
acc_test = np.sum(y_test == y_test_pred, axis=0) / X_test.shape[0]
results.append([acc_train,acc_test])
```

How can reproducibility be guaranteed (independent of the executing device)?

Answer (score 1):

I cannot reproduce this.

If there is something wrong, this would probably need more information about the different machines. What is the result of calling `python -c 'import sklearn; sklearn.show_versions()'` on each?

---

The following code gives me the same result on Ubuntu/Red Hat when `scikit-learn==0.24.2` (I tried with different: `numpy==1.19.1/1.20.2` and `scipy==1.5.2/1.6.3`).

```py
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPClassifier
from sklearn.datasets import load_breast_cancer
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split


X, y = load_breast_cancer(return_X_y=True)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, random_state=0)

clf = MLPClassifier(
    hidden_layer_sizes=(100, 100),
    activation="relu",
    solver="adam",
    alpha=0.001,
    batch_size=50,
    learning_rate_init=0.01,
    max_iter=1000,
    random_state=0,
)

clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
print(clf.score(X_train, y_train))
print(clf.score(X_test, y_test))
```

Output:

```
0.9272300469483568
0.9370629370629371
```